# Method to handle invalid request in a Java Web Application?

Tags: java, date, web, spring-boot, calendar

I have to get two dates in a request parameter lets say `"from=jan 1 2016"` and `"to= feb 1 2016"`. `"from"` should always come before `"to"`.

My controller methods return `Map` in response if `"from"` is before `"to"`, but if `"to=jan 1 2016"` value comes before `"from=feb 1 2016"`, how do I handle the response to send a message?

Comment: post what have u done so far..

Comment: dateFrom.compare(dateTo) = -1 (from < to) / 0 (from = to) / 1 (from > to). So you have to implement the compare method.

Comment: Can you show some code ? It will be better for us to understand things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way would be to throw an exception if anything happens that shouldn't happen. If you're using Java 8 time API (or something like Joda time), you can easily achieve this by using [`isBefore()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```java
if (to.isBefore(from)) {
    // Write your own exception class
    throw new InvalidParameterException("To cannot be before from");
}
```

Now you can use `@ExceptionHandler` to do anything you want if an exception is thrown. For example:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidParameterException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ErrorMessageDTO handleInvalidParameter(InvalidParameterException ex) {
    // Write your own DTO to return an exception
    return new ErrorMessageDTO(ex.getMessage());
}
```

If you want to use dates as request parameters, you might want to use a `Formatter<LocalDate>` to properly do this:

```java
@Component
public class LocalDateStringFormatter implements Formatter<LocalDate> {
    // Or use a custom formatter with a custom pattern
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;

    @Override
    public LocalDate parse(String isoDateString, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return LocalDate.parse(text, FORMATTER);
    }

    @Override
    public String print(LocalDate date, Locale locale) {
        retun date.format(FORMATTER);
    }
}
```

This way you can map `@RequestParam`s of type `LocalDate`.